# Load Datatable after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I've looked for some kind of similar answer in the site but I haven't been able to make do it right.
I need to load the dataTable and all its properties after an onClick event to get the data. The table load fine but the export, sort and search options from the dataTable don't load.

Here is my onClick, at the end I'm inserting the result into a div called tableList

```
            $('#getData').on('click', (event) => {
                var tmp =
                    JSON.stringify({
                        "campaign": '',
                        "function": "getServiceExpertReport",
                        "beginDate": document.getElementById("startDate").value,
                        "endDate": document.getElementById("endDate").value
                    })
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'development_functions.php',
                    headers: 'Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    data: tmp,
                    body: tmp,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $("#tableList").after(result)
                    },
                })
            });
```

And this is the dataTable that I was trying to load after the post call is loaded.

```
            $(document).load(function() {
                $('#agentList').DataTable({
                    paging: true,
                    search: {
                        searching: true,
                        caseInsensitive: true
                    },
                    dom: 'lBfrtip',
                    buttons: true,
                    buttons: [{
                        extend: 'collection',
                        text: 'Export',
                        buttons: [
                            'copy',
                            'excel',
                            'csv',
                            'print'
                        ]
                    }]
                });
            });
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is what you're looking for: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: @icecub Hi, so I added the code but the option still not show up. I updated like this `var table = $('#agentTable').DataTable({`  and in the onClick event I added `table.ajax.reload()`

Comment: The reload should happen _after_ the table has received the new data. So you should not reload on click. Instead, you should reload in the `success` handler after you've put the data into the table.